# Uploaded images in Drupal are being automatically deleted

Tags: image, drupal, upload

I am new to Drupal and have a small problem. When I upload an image using below code, the image is saved successfully. But after some time the image is automatically deleted. So far I have been unable to find the problem.

My code is:

```
file_prepare_directory($_filePath, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY); 
$file = file_save_upload('thumb_img', '', $_filePath);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The file will be added to the {file_managed} table as a temporary file. Temporary files are periodically cleaned. To make the file a permanent file, assign the status and use file_save() to save the changes.

Ref :

1. [file_save_upload](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7)
2. [file_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save/7)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this and was already wondering why the images disappeared. Works fine now. ;-)